# Is there a way to bind to the edit/view mode on DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf

I want to know in my view model whether or not the DataGridTemplateColumn is in edit mode or not. Either a TwoWay or OneWayToSource would be ideal

Comment: You can subscribe to the BeginningEdit event and update properties of the view model from inside the code-behind.